# How to add lines one by one from one file into another file

Tags: python, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have one file called `ClientList.txt` that has a output of:

```
client1.hello.com
client2.hello.com
client3.hello.com
```

I want to append these lines one by one with additional text into my other file called `output.txt` using python.

Example of what I want to achieve in my `output.txt` file:

```
clients name: client1.hello.com, clients URL: client1.hello.com, service: VIP
clients name: client2.hello.com, clients URL: client2.hello.com, service: VIP
clients name: client3.hello.com, clients URL: client3.hello.com, service: VIP
```

Can someone help me achieve this?

What I tried so far:

```
def main():

f= open("output.txt","w+")

for i in range(3):
    f.write("clients name: client1.hello.com, clients URL: client1d.hello.com, service: VIP")
f.close()
```

Output I get:

```
clients name: client1.hello.com, clients URL: client1d.hello.com, service: VIPclients name: client1.hello.com, clients URL: client1d.hello.com, service: VIPclients name: client1.hello.com, clients URL: client1d.hello.com, service: VIP
```

I am new to python, so I am not sure on how to aproach this.

Comment: Sorry for that, edited my original post.

Comment: Add a `\n` after `VIP` in your `write` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this in Python:

```
with open("ClientList.txt", "r") as infile:
    with open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write("".join(["clients name: ",line.strip(), ", clients URL: ", line.strip(), ", service: VIP\n"]))
```

Content in `output.txt`:

```
clients name: client1.hello.com, clients URL: client1.hello.com, service: VIP
clients name: client2.hello.com, clients URL: client2.hello.com, service: VIP
clients name: client3.hello.com, clients URL: client3.hello.com, service: VIP
```

Again, seeing that you edited your post, in order for your code to work your should change the `write` line to the following:

```
f.write("clients name: client1.hello.com, clients URL: client%d.hello.com, service: VIP\n" % (i+1))
```

That should do.

Comment: Let's just say that in the future I would like to edit the client list. Is it possible to not print client1, client2 and client3 if they already exist in the  output.txt file and add client4 and client5 only?

P.S. I don't want to "write" the file again because there will be additional lines without clients name, clients url and service.

Comment: It would be rather difficult to efficiently achieve that, because you 'll have to check every new client against all existing clients. A database that does not allow duplicates would be better.